# Python Parallel Assignments

Tags: python, parallel-assignment

While I thought I understood parallel assignments in Python, I now realize I am unsure. Moreover, for a long time, I saw the parallel assignment paradigm in the following way:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Switch index 1 with index 3
lst[1], lst[3] = lst[3], lst[1]

# Resulting output
# [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
```

In the example above, since the right-hand side of the assignment statement is evaluated first, the values from the original ordering of the list are preserved; that is, `lst[3]` represents the value `4` and `lst[1]` represents the value `2` on the right-hand side of the statement. At the same time, the left-hand side of the assignment statement represents the *locations* to assign these respective values. So, the value of `4` will be assigned to the index location of `1` and the value of `2` will be assigned to the index location of `3`.

While this makes sense, I came across an obscure example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

index = 1
A = index
B = lst[index] + 1

# Switch index A (1) with index B (3)
lst[A], lst[B] = lst[B], lst[A]

# Resulting output
# [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
```

This snippet above works as it is expected to. However, if I slightly alter the code....

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

index = 1

lst[index], lst[lst[index] + 1] = lst[lst[index] + 1], lst[index]

# Resulting Output
# Error
```

This snippet will result in an `IndexError`. Can anyone break down what exactly is occurring here regarding the assignments? Based on my prior exposure to parallel assignments, I would expect the right-hand side of the assignment statement to evaluate to `4` and `2`, just as it had from the previous examples. Then, from there, I would think that `lst[index]` represents the original location of `2` and `lst[index] + 1` represents the original location of `4`. Therefore, the parallel assignment should work as expected, flipping the two values as it did in the previous instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two indices on the left are not precomputed before the first assignment takes place. The entire assignment

```
lst[index], lst[lst[index] + 1] = lst[lst[index] + 1], lst[index]
```

behaves like

```
i1 = lst[index] + 1
lst[index] = lst[li]
i2 = lst[index] + 1
lst[i2] = lsp[index]
```

The assignment on line two changes what value `i2` receives, in this case a value that doesn't correspond to a valid list index.